# Why is my squid farm not spawning squids?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just put a cage around a body of water and there should be squids spawning, but only very few fish spawn.

I first built one in a river then in another river and then one in an ocean biome, where previously squids would spawn. I put blocks around an 8x18 area and the y coordinates range from 62 to 46, but there are zero squid spawns.

I looked up the criteria for squid to spawn and I think the farm meets all of them.

[image: https://imgur.com/NeSczkO] 
This is where the player will afk (23 blocks above the farm)

[image]
This is where the squid are supposed to spawn, but they aren't

Comment: Is it in the right biome?

Comment: this one i built in a luke warm ocean biome. a biome that can spawn squids. the other two i built in non related rivers and they also dont spawn squids

Comment: Maybe there are just many water mobs around already? Try killing them all and see if a few spawn in your farm.

Comment: i killed every squid in the world with /kill @e[type=minecraft:squid] but none of them seem to be spawning in the farm

Comment: Are there any other aquatic mobs nearby? Aquatic mobs have a [mob density](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Bedrock_Edition) of 4, meaning that if there are 4 aquatic mobs within a 9×9 square area around eligible spawning chunks, no squids will spawn.

Comment: oh thx man i'll check

Comment: Also, could you update this with what version of minecraft you are playing?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is more water outside of your farm then inside, more squids spawn outside of the bounds of your farm then inside it. You need to remove all the water outside of your farm to a distance of `128 blocks` from your player(the distance at which mobs stop spawning). You also need to make sure that when you use your farm that you stand at least `25 blocks` away from your farm, for that is the distance at which mobs start spawning.

Remember, if mobs are spawning outside your farm, they are therefore not spawning inside your farm.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a bedrock version then you are simply unable to have the squid spawn on the river biomes.  In any other situation here you would have to be careful with the overall aquatic mob cap which can damper your trap designs within a roughly 128 block radius from the player.  Finally, if you have any nether portals roughly 250 blocks away from the spawn point you would have to worry about the cap limits if you use those nether portals.